# Improving the time it takes to precompile a large ASP.NET WebForms application

Tags: asp.net, aspnet-compiler

Consider having large ASP.NET web forms application with thousands of pages and controls with thousands of page views per second. The application was originally written in ASP.NET 1.0 and have been maintained since then. Today it runs using ASP.NET v4.5.

On a 24 core, 32 GB workstation, it takes **4 to 6 hours** to precompile the website using the following command line.

```
aspnet_compiler -f /v / -p .\MyApp -d .\Precompiled -fixednames
```

CPU usage is limited to 2% to 5% and memory usage remains the same.  In essence, the utility is not making use of the hardware.

When building it without `-fixednames` it takes approx 30 minutes, but intermittently fails with an error

```
Circular file references are not allowed
```

The due to the complexity of the application, refactoring it is considered too risky.

There is a lot of references to aspnet_compiler, but I can't find any pertaining to very large web applications.

Is there anything in particular you'd do to improve the performance of aspnet_compiler?

Comment: Are you using SSD or a HDD? that can have a great speed improvement  especially if your project has many files.

Comment: I have an SSD as my primary and a normal HDD as a secondary. The source is located on the primary.